# Не сохраняются настройки Ethernet в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

Установил официальный дистрибутив Ubuntu 14.04 на ноутбук hp. В свежеустановленной ОС не могу применить настройки для соединения "Wired connection 1". При нажатии на кнопку "Options.." в "All Settings -> Network" открывается единожды модальное окно, в которое ввожу верные настройки провайдера (MAC-адрес, IPv4 адреса, DNS). При последующих попытках открыть данное окно получаю ошибку:

```
assertion `uuid != NULL' failed
```

Имеется тот же установленный дистрибутив на ПК - настройки успешно применились. Копирую конфиг с ПК на ноутбук, расположенный по адресу:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1

[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=f27f2946-a3f8-4982-acb7-4d64ba4050b5
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1454749932

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
dns-search=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
address1=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX,XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Не помогло. Пытался переустановить дистрибутив убунту повторно на ноутбук, скопировал конфиг сразу, не открывая модальное окно - не получилось.

Открывал от root настройки сети:

```
sudo unity-control-center network
```

Менял настройки - тоже безуспешно. Настройки не применяются, ощущение будто бы игнорирует конфиги.

Как применить настройки сети в Ubuntu 14.04 на ноутбуке hp ?

Comment: Еще хочу добавить, что до этого прежде на этом ноуте стояла fedora 25 версии, на которой все настройки прям с первого раза подхватились, и появился интернет.

Comment: Пробовали без `NetworkManager` прописать настройки вручную в `/etc/network/interfaces`? Может ну его, этот `NetworkManager`?

Comment: @zombic спасибо за отклик. Не доводилось, смогу попробовать только вечером. На работе сейчас тоже ubuntu, имеется только такой путь /etc/network/interfaces.d , внутри ничего нет (ls -laF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что "подсовывался" mac-адрес сетевой карты ноутбука. Принудительно подставил нужный в ifconfig:

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

Правда, автоматическая эта служба о сих пор не могла подключиться (из-за отсутствия доп настроек IPv4), и что интересно - скидывала MAC-адрес обратно. Пришлось повторить процедуру. Суть в том, что стала нажиматься кнопка с настройками соединения (та ошибка с NULL на самом деле означала несоответствие uuid-хэшей мак-адресов). По нажатии я заметил, что в NetworkManager создался-таки конфигурационный файл. Туда-то я и вписал IPv4 нужные руками. Также в cloned MAC-address указал нужный, а в первом поле - заводской. Все перезагрузил и соединение установилось